# How do I select this field in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I know it is probably a simple solution but for some reason I am having trouble calling it... I tried querying it then calling 
`user.connected_accounts.facebook` but that does not work... I need to get hte number out.

Here is the code:

```
"connected_accounts":[{"facebook":"5555555"}],
```

Here is my mongoose schema:

```
 connected_accounts: {type: Array}
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  I'm not sure what you're asking as "the code" you show isn't really code.

Comment: I figured it out already, thanks tho!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you question, I want to know you query clause, in mongodb console, it is different when you are using [db.collection.find](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) method and [db.collection.findOne](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/) method, find method will return an collections, but findOne method will return one object(docment).

So if you are using find, you can get result like:  `results[0].connected_accounts[0].facebook` , if you are using findOne, you can get result like: `results.connected_accounts[0].facebook`.

Answer (score 0):

I had to just called `connected_account[0].facebook` to get the value.